# Why my kernel log is not showing the latest output?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I'm coding a simple kernel module, in Ubuntu 17.04, that takes a string and prints it in the kernel log.

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/moduleparam.h>
char* mystring = "hello world";
module_param(mystring ,charp ,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

void display(void){
printk(KERN_ALERT "%s" ,mystring);
}
static int hello(void){
//printk(KERN_ALERT "hello module");
display();
return 0;
} 
static void bye(void){
printk(KERN_ALERT "bye");
}
module_init(hello);
module_exit(bye);
```

I run command `make` and then when I run `insmod test.ko mystring="blahblahblah"`, the module will be inserted correctly but when I run `dmesg` it doesn't show the `blahblahblah`.

After I run `rmmod test.ko` and `dmseg` the expression `blahblahblah` will appear in the terminal. When I run `insmod test.ko mystring="blahblahblah"` again and then `dmesg` the `blahblahblah` will be printed.

what is the problem exactly? Is it my problem or the system?

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes `printk` may defer output (that is, message is stored in the internal buffer, but not in kernel log). To avoid such behavior, always add newline (`\n`) at the end of the string printed:

```
printk(KERN_ALERT "%s\n" ,mystring);
```