# printk messages not showing up in dmesg log

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dmesg

I'm developing a simple driver for fun, and I'm trying to debug it with `printk` messages. It seems that `dmesg` doesn't display the last `printk` message, and the only way to get it to show the last message is by doing another `printk`, which in turn is also swallowed by `dmesg`.

Some examples for clarification:
in my module's init function I print the following statement:

```
printk(KERN_INFO "%s loaded with major: %u, minor: 0", ...);
```

After `insmod`ing for the first time after a boot, I see a "tainted kernel" message with `dmesg`, however I can't see the message I printed.

Then, I run the following command:

```
cat /dev/mymodule
```

which invokes my `open` function which prints:

```
printk(KERN_DEBUG "%s opened", ...);
```

and then invokes my `read` function which prints:

```
printk(KERN_DEBUG "%s reading", current->comm);
```

and then goes to sleep. After running `dmesg` (while the read function sleeps), I can suddenly see my module init message, and I can also see the "cat opened" message, however the "cat reading" message is missing.

Terminating cat with ctrl+c causes two prints: "sleep interrupted", and then "cat released". Running `dmesg` shows the "sleep interrupted" message, but the "cat released" message is missing, and so on.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: I guess that the problem might be that there is no `newline` symbol at the end of line. Try simply print `\n` in last line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why my kernel log is not showing the latest output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47589197/why-my-kernel-log-is-not-showing-the-latest-output)

Comment: The newline was indeed the problem! Could you add your comment as an answer? I'd like to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add \n at end of every printk message not to miss any logs in the dmesg. This will solve your problem.