# insmod printk doesn't work, but works for rmmod

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, centos7

Since I'm still learning about kernel module programming, unable to figure out the rational behind the issue. When I run `insmod hello.ko`, `dmesg or /var/logs/message` doesn't show/print the message, whereas when I run `rmmod hello.ko`, `dmesg or /var/logs/message` shows/print string from `hello_init(void) and hello_exit(void)`.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");


static int hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello World!!");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Bye World!");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why my kernel log is not showing the latest output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47589197/why-my-kernel-log-is-not-showing-the-latest-output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printk` is very newline aware. The `printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello World!!");` doesn't print anything because it doesn't has a newline. It awaits the next `printk(KERN_CONT` as a continuation of the line and the next `prinkt(KERN_CONT` with a newline. It get's printed on the next `printk(KERN_ALERT` because then `printk` assumes that the last line has ended and prints it. If you want to output it immediately add a newline to the format string.

So just:

```
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello World!!\n");
```

Comment: It’s not because of kernel, it’s due `\n` has special meaning for buffered output.