# Initialization and Cleanup are swapped around in Kernel Module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

Currently studying kernel modules, and we tasked with writing a small Hello World / Bye World kernel module (in C). Got the idea pretty quick and had a rough idea of what I should do.

Needed to make the initialization function print a Hello message, and the clean up function to print a Bye message. The initialization message should print when I add the kernel module to the list of modules (working on a Debian VM) using ***insmod***, and the cleanup message should print when I remove the module using ***rmmod***.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
#define MODULE
#define LINUX
#define __KERNEL__

#include <linux/module.h>   // all modules
#include <linux/kernel.h>   // KERN_ALERT and potentially other priorities
#include <linux/init.h>     // macros

static int __init do_initialization(void) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello World :)");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit do_cleanup(void){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Bye bye :)");
}

module_init(do_initialization);
module_exit(do_cleanup);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("A");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Exercise");
MODULE_VERSION("1.00");
```

This is the Makefile I use (this was provided to us but I understand most of it):

```
obj-m += mymodule.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

NB: I use KERN_ALERT instead of KERN_INFO just to make sure that it displays on my terminal regardless.

My problem lies in the following:
When I run **insmod mymodule.ko**, the Bye Bye message is printed. When I run **rmmod mymodule.ko**, the Hello message is printed. It really doesn't make any sense to me, and I made sure that my functions are correctly set inside the macros.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you have changed the code and forgot to recompile it. Change your messages to something different and recompile to make sure.

Comment: not the case unfortunately, changed the messages (added a few words after Bye Bye for example) a few times around to make sure my compilation is up to date (which it was).

Comment: Well, that sounds weird.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why my kernel log is not showing the latest output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47589197/why-my-kernel-log-is-not-showing-the-latest-output)

Comment: All three first `#define` are wrong: The macros like `MODULE` are defined by the build system automatically when needed.

Comment: yes it does! thank you so much. please let me know how I can highlight your comment as a correct answer / close the thread

Comment: It should be some button at the top of the question, which means that you (as the author of the question) agree with the suggested duplicate.

Comment: You should use `\n` when logging the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by the link that Tsyvarev added as a comment to the question on 1st March 2021, and by the answer by Roi on 2nd March 2021, **I simply needed to add \n when logging the kernel.** Thank you to everyone who helped.